# How do I get the "lost" bit from a bit shift?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bit-manipulation

I want to bit shift a variable and store the bit that's shifted out in a boolean.

Something like:

```
unsigned int i = 1;
bool b = rshift(&i); // i now equals 0 and b is set to true
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: are you looking for a rotation function, i.e. what is shifted out on the one side is re-inserted on the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to capture the bit *before* the shift:

```
bool rshift(unsigned int* p) {
    bool ret = (*p) & 1;
    *p >>= 1;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That’s what I’d have said too. I’d love to see how the different compilers generate this code or if an inline asm section could do better.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't it considered bad practice to return a bool when the returned value isn't really a "boolean value" in actual? I know that a bool still takes 8-bits (a byte) and so does char...
So shouldn't one use like an 8-bit int (uint8_t) for this purpose?

Comment: @mtahmed: Just a question of semantics. If you specify `rshift` to return whether the value pointed to was odd, it's suddenly a truly boolean result.

Comment: @qdii: Many years ago when I programmed in assembly, the "lost" bit was stored in the flag register and easy to access. Not sure if that's still the case or the most efficient method to get the lost bit.

Comment: @mtahmed: Your assumption is wrong; a `bool` may take more than one byte. 32 is common (register size). But using `bool` is a strong message to the compiler that you will use only one bit of it, and the compiler may optimize for this.

Comment: Bit shifting does, in fact, set the carry flag at machine code level. Perhaps asm would do a better job of this.

Answer (score 6):

You don't.  You have to test it before the shift:

```
bool
rshift( unsigned& i )
{
    bool results = (i & 0x01) != 0;
    i >>= 1;
    return results;
}
```

(This is simple for a right shift.  For a left shift, you have to know
the number of bits in the word.)

Comment: For a left shift there are other options which don't require that you know the number of bits: `unsigned copy = (i<<1)>>1; bool results = (copy != i); i <<= 1;`. Such a left-right shift will portably drop the top bit(s).

Comment: @MSalters The left right shift is required to drop the top bits (for an unsigned type).  Still, I'd want a comment to explain what was going on; I'd probably use something like `1 << (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT) - 1)` as a mask.  Not as transparent as I'd like either, but IMHO not quite as opaque as the double shift.

Answer (score 4):

To do this for any shift, and any type, reverse the operation (to check whether you lost something).

```
template <typename T> bool rshift(T& val) {
  T const original = val;
  return ((val >>= 1) << 1) != original;
}
template <typename T> bool lshift(T& val) {
  T const original = val;
  return ((val <<= 1) >> 1) != original;
}
```

Comment: That's a good way of doing it, but the way you wrote it the function does not actually modify `val`. So it's slightly different from the original requirement.

Comment: @jogojapan: I don't get your point. Why do you think `val` isn't changed? It is passed as non-const reference and changed in `val <<= 1`.

Comment: You're right. I saw only `<<` where there was really `<<=`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a rotate function, you could try the following.

At first, have a meta function to get the number of bits of the to-be-rotated value (note: `8*sizeof(T)` wouldn't be portable; the standard only dictates at least 8 bits):

```
#include <climits>
template <typename T>
struct bits { enum { value = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T) }; };
```

Next, define a function for rightway rotation. It does so by applying a right-shift as expected, and a left-shift to shift up what would be cancelled out otherwise:

```
template <unsigned int N, typename T>
T rotate_right (T value)
{
    enum { left = bits<T>::value - N };
    return (value>>N) | (value<<left);
}
```

Have a diagnosis function for testing, and test:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void print_bits (std::ostream &os, T value)
{
    for (unsigned int i=bits<T>::value; i!=0; --i)
        os << ((value>>(i-1))&1);
}

    int main () {
    char c = 1,
         c_ = rotate_right<1>(c);

    unsigned long long ull = 0xF0F0C0C050503030, 
                       ull_ = rotate_right<63>(ull);

    std::cout << "c ="; print_bits(std::cout, c);  std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "c'="; print_bits(std::cout, c_); std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "ull ="; print_bits(std::cout, ull);  std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "ull'="; print_bits(std::cout, ull_); std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
c =00000001
c'=10000000
ull =1111000011110000110000001100000001010000010100000011000000110000
ull'=1110000111100001100000011000000010100000101000000110000001100001
```

A left-rotation can be implemented similarly, or in terms of the right-rotation.

As for performance, g++ detects the idiom and uses a rotation instruction on x86 and amd64.

```
g++ -std=c++0x -S main.cc
cat main.s

...
sarl %eax
...
```

Comment: +1 It's a great answer, if though it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to the suggestions made so far:

```
bool rshift(int32_t &i) {
  long long i2 = (static_cast<int64_t>(i) << 31);
  i = (i2 >> 32);
  return static_cast<int32_t>(i2);
}
```

This assumes the `int` is what `int` usually means these days, i.e. `int32_t`. It copies it into a `int64_t`, then performs the shift, copies the higher 32 bits into `i` and then returns the lower 32 bits (which contain the shifted `1`) as a bool.

I don't know if that is faster than the other approaches. The *added benefit* of this general approach is that it can be used to retrieve more than a single bit, e.g. if you shift by 2 or more bits.

Comment: I do no see any benefit in this code. 0) it is not general, it assumes 32 bit integers. What if any platform will set the size of integers to 33 bits, 40 bits, or 64 bits? Then you'll have a silent and hard to track down bug. 1) Why do you use `i2 >> 32` instead of just `i>>=31`? 2) `static_cast<bool>(static_cast<int>(i2))`??

Comment: What I mean by "this general approach" is: Any approach that, rather than shifting the bits away and losing them, expands the int to 64 bits before shifting, so the bits that were shifted out of focus can be retrieved. Implementing this in a way that works for non-32-bit integers would be possible, although I doubt that 33-bit integers etc. are relevant for anything. Re 1): `i` is 32 bits, `i2` 64 bits in length. I have edited the text to make this unambiguous. Re 2): The cast to 32 bit is to extract the lower 32 bits of the total 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small c# demo for bit grabbing:

```
using System;
class BitToBoolArray {
  static void Main() {
  
  ushort guiMask = 0b1100_1100_0011_0011;
  
    bool[] boxEnabled = new bool[16]; 
    
    for (int i=0;i<16;guiMask>>=1,++i) 
    {
        
        bool bit =  (guiMask & 0x0001) == 1 ;
        boxEnabled[i] = bit;
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nBit position: {0} , Bit: {1}",i,bit);
    }
    

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right shift is the most common way to get the bits from a variable, the problem is that the result comes in backwards, and this is kinda boring. There's a way to get the binary as it is inside the variable, that is the following:

The strategy is mask a part of the bits, like in the right shift, but now targeting the most significant bit, a binary constant accomplish very well this requirement.

```
unsigned int number = 2863311530;
unsigned int mostSignificantBit = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;

// Masking a number by a binary that only has the
// most significant bit set will result in the
// same binary if the most significant bit of the 
// variable was 1. 
if((number & mostSignificantBit) == mostSignificantBit){
    printf("1");
}else{
    printf("0");
}
```

Dumping the whole binary content of a variable would look like this:

```
// The good part of using bitwise operations is that
// signed and unsigned values really don't matter,
// the only thing that bitwise operations care about is binary.
int number = -123456;
unsigned int mostSignificantBit = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    if((number & mostSignificantBit) == mostSignificantBit){
        printf("1");
    }else{
        printf("0");
    }

    number = number << 1;
}

printf("\n");

// Result: 11111111111111100001110111000000
// this binary is really the 2's complement of
// the number -123456
```

### Some alerts

The previous example works very fine! however, different architectures/platforms or even compilers can define the total of bits that a  int can hold with different sizes. The good news is that this isn't hard to handle. The header <stdint.h> implements data types that hold a fixed number of bits, for instance:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void){
    int16_t sixteenBitsInt;
    uint16_t unsignedSixteenBitsInt;
    int32_t thirtyTwoBitsInt;
    uint32_t unsignedThirtyTwoBitsInt;

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

But if for any reason you don't wan't use fixed data lengths, there's more one away that you can use to accomplish this, even if there's different sizes of integers in cross-platforms environments.

The strategy here is get a binary that has only the most significant bit set,  regardless the size of the variable. Following the binary logic, if you get the max unsigned value of a variable, divide it by 2 and add the value 1, you will get this necessary binary, for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT UINT_MAX / 2 + 1
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef unsigned char bool;

int main(void){
    int number = -123456;
    unsigned int mostSignificantBit = MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT;
    bool stopFlag = FALSE;
    // By the reason of the numbers of bits may be variable,
    // we need divide a UINT_MAX until reach 0 to be sure that
    // there's no more bits to be shifted.
    unsigned int max = UINT_MAX;

    while(stopFlag == FALSE){
        if((number & mostSignificantBit) == mostSignificantBit){
            printf("1");
        }else{
            printf("0");
        }

        // Updating the max here allows the
        // algorithm to run more one time after 
        // reaching the "0". Doing this calculation
        // inside the while would make the program
        // let one bit behind inside the number.
        max /= 2;
        if(max == 0){
            stopFlag = TRUE;
        }

        number = number << 1;
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Result: 11111111111111100001110111000000
    // This binary is the 2's complement of the
    // number -123456, and is the same of the previous
    // example of variable dumping.

    return 0;
}
```

The macro UINT_MAX and its siblings will hold different values across platforms with the goal of specify the max value of a given data type, allowing this implementation be cross-platform. Using fixed length data types is really easier, but this is also a useful solution.